# Convert XML to JSON object in Android

Tags: android, xml, json, libraries

I have an XML string as shown below:

```
<s:Envelope 
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><Response 
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><UserResult><Users xmlns=""><User>
<Message>Success</Message>
<UserId>213213213</UserId>
<FullName>Abc</FullName>
<Roles>
<Role>
<RoleId>23232333</RoleId>
<RoleName>Salesperson</RoleName>
</Role>
</Roles>
</User>
</Users>
</UserResult></Response>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Is it possible to convert XML to JSON?

Comment: You may use online tool. https://javadev.github.io/xml-to-json/

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can try this way as well. I have tried and tested it myself.

Step 1 : Please Download the [java-json.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip)

Step 2: Add this to `/libs` folder of your project then add to build path.

Step 3: Then use it as follows

- Imports to look for

  ```
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;
  import org.json.XML;
  ```
- Sample string

  ```
  String sampleXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
      + "<mobilegate>"    
  +"<timestamp>232423423423</timestamp>"                          
  + "<txn>" + "Transaction" + "</txn>" 
  + "<amt>" + 0 + "</amt>" 
  + "</mobilegate>";
  ```
- Json String

  ```
  JSONObject jsonObj = null;
  try {
      jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(sampleXml);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.e("JSON exception", e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
  } 

  Log.d("XML", sampleXml);

  Log.d("JSON", jsonObj.toString());
  ```

**Output:**

**XML:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mobilegate><timestamp>232423423423</timestamp><txn>Transaction</txn><amt>0</amt></mobilegate>`

**JSON :**

`{"mobilegate":{"timestamp":232423423423,"amt":0,"txn":"Transaction"}}`

Comment: Save a lot of my time. Thanks!

Comment: @RiteshGune if xml contains <![CDATA[ 26 ]]> , the app crashes. is there any solution for this?? i found a similar problem here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283261/converting-xml-to-json-android

Comment: Is it good practice to convert xml to json? I mean, I like json a hell of a lot more, but just wondering if this is an OK thing to do. Could there be potential hick-ups in your android app later by doing this? (e.g. maybe xml data changes in such a way that the json makes no sense)

Comment: @MicroR IMHO ,whether it is a good practice or not is a different question. using xml or json has its own pros and cons, however there may be few cases where one might need to convert xml to json. Hence the selection has to be based on requirement so that one doesn't have to convert

Comment: import org.json.XML not found, if someone have library which contains such file, kindly share. I can share my email id. 
Great Thnx

Comment: @AbdulWahab; Please help, which lib u used when u faced this XML not found error, I am getting the same

Comment: @ChanderShakherGhorela-Guru I had the same issue. I added     `compile files('libs/java-json.jar')` in my build.gradle, synced the project and the error message disappeared.

Comment: @ChanderShakherGhorela-Guru if  the solution PanagiotisNto doesn't work try clicking File then invalidate cache / restart and then click on invalidate and restart.  that can also help sometimes.

Comment: @PanagiotisNto  & Randrm Thanks for your comment, But I changed the location of java-json.jar from libs to other package, and again imported through new path, this way its worked for me. :)

Comment: @RiteshGune This lib is not cover CDATA tag

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method end()Z in class Lorg/json/XMLTokener; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.json.XMLTokener' appears in /data/app/`
This is the error it gives while converting the data in android studio.

Answer (score 11):

I just released a "XML to JSON" Library for Android Studio.
It is easy to integrate with gradle, simple to use, and configurable.

**XmlToJson** is available on GitHub:

https://github.com/smart-fun/XmlToJson

enjoy!

Comment: Works for me.  And more importantly, was very easy to edit to use the 'json-smart' library instead of the atrocious 'org.json' implementation.  I can't stand `JSONException`.

Comment: hey , I checked your initiative. It is nice.some values like "' "issn": "00368733" -> behave in your solution like ""issn": 368733," . The first digits with zeros are dropping. Just for your info bro..

Comment: And the list values also breaking with {} brackets.

Comment: Dear Friend,

Unable to implement the library.
Here is what I'm adding in  APP build.gradle file :

implementation 'com.github.smart-fun:XmlToJson:1.4.5'

Getting the following error:
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.smart-fun:XmlToJson:1.4.5

Comment: Petros probably you forgot to add the jitpack information in the PROJECT build.gradle? maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

Comment: I chose this library, because it very easily parsed an xml string which had 310k lines, Underscore java port library took 5 minutes >.<

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `json-lib`, a library which adds `JSON support to any Java program`. json-lib can take XML and convert it into a JSON object.

You can get json-lib [here](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Eg.

```
String xml = "your xml string";                
XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
JSON json = xmlSerializer.read( xml );
```

Comment: i have tried using json lib but got NoSuchMethodError exception

Comment: could you please paste logcat

Comment: caused by: java.lang.verifyError: net/sf/json/xml/XMLSerializer

Comment: did you add the jar to build path?

Comment: while use this jar, getting this error..02-04 15:43:52.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10269): java.lang.VerifyError: net/sf/json/xml/XMLSerializer

Answer (score 2):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) has static method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QdM)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = "<s:Envelope \n"
                    + "xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body><Response \n"
                    + "xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><UserResult><Users xmlns=\"\"><User>\n"
                    + "<Message>Success</Message>\n"
                    + "<UserId>213213213</UserId>\n"
                    + "<FullName>Abc</FullName>\n"
                    + "<Roles>\n"
                    + "<Role>\n"
                    + "<RoleId>23232333</RoleId>\n"
                    + "<RoleName>Salesperson</RoleName>\n"
                    + "</Role>\n"
                    + "</Roles>\n"
                    + "</User>\n"
                    + "</Users>\n"
                    + "</UserResult></Response>\n"
                    + "</s:Body>\n"
                    + "</s:Envelope>";
        System.out.println(U.xmlToJson(xml));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "s:Envelope": {
    "-xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "s:Body": {
      "Response": {
        "-xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/",
        "UserResult": {
          "Users": {
            "-xmlns": "",
            "User": {
              "Message": "Success",
              "UserId": "213213213",
              "FullName": "Abc",
              "Roles": {
                "Role": {
                  "RoleId": "23232333",
                  "RoleName": "Salesperson"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```

Comment: Tried with a good XML string and got the following error                 `javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd` Unfortunately the link is broken so no help there

Answer (score 0):

You can convert xml to jackson objects, and then can use jackson json.

I have attempted to add XmlPull support to jackson xml. Find the forked project here:

https://github.com/finvu/jackson-dataformat-xml

Currently, only supported for version 2.9.6. (clone the branch jackson-dataformat-xml-2.9.6-XmlPull)

Sorry, I am not able to provide detailed documentation due to time constraints. If you have knowledge of git and maven to pull a specific branch and build the jar, then it should be relatively easy.

Jackson xml documentation can be found on the jackson xml git home page here:

https://github.com/finvu/jackson-dataformat-xml/tree/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.9.6-XmlPull

Comment: Underscore-java converts xml to json better. Live example, mit license, one static method.