# How to parse data in Json farmet using google http client (Android app)?

Tags: android, json, google-http-client

I am getting data from server by building a get request (HttpRequest). The data is not in Json format (when I open the link in a web browser, it says "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.")

Since it is the case, when I call this line:

```
HttpRequest request = buildGetRequest("TreeLocation");
final LocationListResponse response = request.execute().parseAs(getResultType());
```

The app stops there, and I think it is because it does not regconize the resultType.

So, now I want to declare the content type as Json. Anyone knows how to declare the content type in Google http client library?

Answer (score 0):

just convert your xml response into json using json library..and then you will get json response

use this link [Convert XML to JSON object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337394/convert-xml-to-json-object-in-android)

Edit 1:

you can add this and try

```
 httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

for json respomse