# Android XML parser only retrieving the first item from feed

Tags: android, xml, android-xmlpullparser

I'm creating a small app to read in the BBC f1 news feed into android and to display in a `ListView`. I have created the below parsing functions by following this [Android Developer Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html).

When  the `items ArrayList` is returned to the activity it only has one item, the most recent news story. When I log the

These functions are called after successfully retrieving the data via a async call. On the second to last line the output title is the same as the returned array item.

I have posted the logcat output to pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/NBDqt6aY)

**RSS Structure**

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        // unrequired tags (title, description, lang etc)
        <item>
            <title></title>
            <description></description>
            <link></link>
            <guid isPermaLink="false"></guid>
            <pubDate></pubDate>
            <media:thumbnail  />
            <media:thumbnail  />
        </item>
        <item>
            <title></title>
            <description></description>
            <link></link>
            <guid isPermaLink="false"></guid>
            <pubDate></pubDate>
            <media:thumbnail  />
            <media:thumbnail  />
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

**read feed function**

```
private static ArrayList<BBCItem> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    //Log.d("read feed", "");
    ArrayList<BBCItem> items = new ArrayList();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        // Starts by looking for the channel tag
        if (name.equals("channel")) {
            // navigate to the item tag here
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "channel");
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("item")){
                    items.add(bbcReadEntry(parser));
                }
                else {
                    skip(parser);
                }
            }
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

**read individual feed item**

```
public static BBCItem bbcReadEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "item");
    String title = null;
    String description = null;
    String url = null;
    String pubDate = null;
    String thumbnailURL = null;
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("title")) {
            title = readString(parser, "title");
        } else if (name.equals("description")) {
            description = readString(parser, "description");
        } else if (name.equals("link")) {
            url = readString(parser, "link");
        } else if (name.equals("pubDate")) {
            pubDate = readString(parser, "pubDate");
        } else if (name.equals("media:thumbnail")) {
            //thumbnailURL = readThumbnail(parser);
            thumbnailURL = "http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/81615000/jpg/_81615988_nicorosberg.jpg";
        }
        else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    Log.d("News item title", title);
    return new BBCItem(title, description, url, pubDate, thumbnailURL);
}
```

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to get this working full. Instead I converted the XML string to JSON and manipulated that (which I'm much more comfortable with).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18339178/3194491) is how I converted it from XML to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into almost identical issue when working on something here. I was trying to parse the xml in a rss feed xml file. Same thing happened that i only got the first "item". I was also considering to convert the xml to json and more easily handle it as a json. But i finally managed to make it work for me with the xml file without converstsion to json. What goes wrong here is links that do not have a END_TAG like in my case this caused the problem:

```
<enclosure url="http:/blabla....mp3" length="123456" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

In your case this might cause same issue:

```
<media:thumbnail  />
```

After following this google documentation page https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html , lots of testing and head scratching i resolved the issue by after getting the "url" attribute, calling the method "skip(parser)" directly after getting the "url" attribute value. That single line fixed the issue for my part. I am assuming that the parser then steps out of that TAG and continues with the remaining ones. Hope its of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have just had a similar issue when trying to parse the Scientific American technology RSS feed. In the Android developers document, the readFeed() method looks like:

```
private List readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
List entries = new ArrayList();

parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "feed");
while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        continue;
    }
    String name = parser.getName();
    // Starts by looking for the entry tag
    if (name.equals("entry")) {
        entries.add(readEntry(parser));
    } else {
        skip(parser);
    }
}
return entries;}
```

The reason why my code only sends back the first item in the RSS feed is because (after logging the entry in the line "entries.add(readEntry(parser));", it gets to the end of the RSS item entry and hits the line:

```
while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
```

This in effect terminates the RSS parsing, and you then hit the "return entries;" line which returns the entries ArrayList with one item in.

To fix it (at least it worked for me), just amend the "END_TAG" to "END_DOCUMENT" and it works perfectly.

```
while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
```

I just hope this helps someone, as I have been faffing about with this all day :-) Good luck with the XML parsing.