# How to Parse Complex XML file Locally in android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

How to parse this XML file locally in android ?

```
  <root>
        <Questions>
        <element>
          <answer>1</answer>
          <category>15</category>
          <date_added>2014-05-01 02:10:33</date_added>
          <id>7</id>
          <mode>easy</mode>
           <options>
               <element>2007</element>
               <element>2005</element>
               <element>2006</element>
               <element>2008</element>
            </options>
          <question>When did the first Apple iPhone become available?</question>
        </element>
         <element>
           <answer>3</answer>
           <category>13</category>
           <date_added>2014-05-01 02:14:30</date_added>
           <id>8</id>
           <mode>easy</mode>
            <options>
              <element>carnivores</element>
              <element>omnivores</element>
              <element>herbivores</element>
              <element>insectivores</element>
             </options>
         <question>Are Gorillas ______?</question>
         </element>
    </Questions>
 </root>
```

The above XML file is the file I have to parse locally. I put the XML file into assets folder. It looks like a bit complex XML file. I don’t know how to parse this. Please help me for this. Each and every help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. What i did was that, I convert the XML file to JSON file using a jar file and parsed from there. It works for me.

[Convert XML to JSON object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337394/convert-xml-to-json-object-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Tons of libraries out there for XML parsing so it's hard to give a definite answer here. [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) is pretty simple to use, you could give that a try :)