# parsing xml returns only last row

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this XML

```
<CurrencyExchangeMap>
<CurrencyExchangePoint>
    <Address>addr 3</Address>
    <Latitude>41.6940265</Latitude>
    <Longitude>44.7985044</Longitude>
</CurrencyExchangePoint>
<CurrencyExchangePoint>
    <Address>addr 4</Address>
    <Latitude>41.7024424</Latitude>
    <Longitude>44.8058617</Longitude>
</CurrencyExchangePoint>
<CurrencyExchangePoint>
    <Address>addr 5</Address>
    <Latitude>41.6954418</Latitude>
    <Longitude>44.7046725</Longitude>
</CurrencyExchangePoint>
</CurrencyExchangeMap>
```

And I'm parsing it using:

List mapLTList;

```
private MapLT mapLT;
private String text;

public XMLPullParserHandler() {
    mapLTList = new ArrayList<MapLT>();
}

public List<MapLT> getMapLT(){
    return mapLTList;
}

public List<MapLT> parse(InputStream is){
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
    XmlPullParser parser = null;

    try{
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(is, null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("CurrencyExchangeMap")){
                        mapLT = new MapLT();
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("CurrencyExchangePoint")){
                        mapLTList.add(mapLT);
                    } else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Address")){
                        mapLT.setAddress(text);
                    } else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Latitude")){
                        mapLT.setLatitude(Float.parseFloat(text));
                    } else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Longitude")){
                        mapLT.setLongitude(Float.parseFloat(text));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  mapLTList;
}
```

**BUT** in result there are 3 address and each of them are `Addr 5` (last element). What's wrong?

Comment: Where is the handling of CurrencyExchangePoint in startTag?

Comment: If you are still not able to parse xml then simple best way is convert xml to json and you can parse json easily and here is link for convert xml to json string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337394/convert-xml-to-json-object-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your MapLit contains information about `CurrencyExchangePoint` (three items in your xml), but you are treating it as `CurrencyExchangeMap` (one item in your xml). This way you are reusing the same reference over and over, overriding its content. Change

```
  case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
      if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("CurrencyExchangeMap")){
             mapLT = new MapLT();
      }
```

with

```
case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
  if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("CurrencyExchangePoint")){
         mapLT = new MapLT();
  }
```