# How to Parse JSONArray Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

How can I parse a JSONArray when the response from the webservice is formatted as such:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.somewebsite.com/"><PricingTier ANo='01234567' MsgFlg=''><Group Type='Mouldings'><CurTier>BRZ</CurTier><NxtTier>SIL</NxtTier><CurTierFrom>$4,000</CurTierFrom><CurTierTo>$9,999</CurTierTo><NxtTierFrom>$10,000</NxtTierFrom><NxtTierTo>$14,999</NxtTierTo><CurSales>$2,107</CurSales><ReqSales>$7,893</ReqSales><MsgFull></MsgFull><MsgPart></MsgPart></Group><Group Type='Accessories'><CurTier>BAS</CurTier><NxtTier>GLD</NxtTier><CurTierFrom>$0</CurTierFrom><CurTierTo>$1,499</CurTierTo><NxtTierFrom>$1,500</NxtTierFrom><NxtTierTo>$4,999</NxtTierTo><CurSales>$125</CurSales><ReqSales>$800</ReqSales><MsgFull></MsgFull><MsgPart></MsgPart></Group></PricingTier></string>
```

When I run my application, I get an error saying "Cannot convert string to JSONObject". I know it does not like how to the string response is formatted, so I am wondering what amendment I can make to format the response(JSON_DATA) to something the parser can properly use.

Code:

```
 if (JSON_DATA != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(JSON_DATA);

                JSONArray Group = reader.getJSONArray("Group");

                for (int i = 0; i < Group.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject g = Group.getJSONObject(i);

                    final String Type = g.getString("-Type");
                    final String CurTier = g.getString("CurTier");
                    final String NxtTier = g.getString("NxtTier");
                    final String CurTierFrom = g.getString("CurTierFrom");
                    final String CurTierTo = g.getString("CurTierTo");
                    final String NxtTierFrom = g.getString("NxtTierFrom");
                    final String NxtTierTo = g.getString("NxtTierTo");
                    final String CurSales = g.getString("CurSales");
                    final String ReqSales = g.getString("ReqSales");

                    fragment.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tvType.setText(Type);
                            tvCurTier.setText(CurTier);
                            tvNxtTier.setText(NxtTier);
                            tvCurTierFrom.setText(CurTierFrom);
                            tvCurTierTo.setText(CurTierTo);
                            tvNxtTierFrom.setText(NxtTierFrom);
                            tvNxtTierTo.setText(NxtTierTo);
                            tvCurSales.setText(CurSales);
                            tvReqSales.setText(ReqSales);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Your input is in xml refer this answer on how to convert xml string to JSONObject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18339178/5245903

Comment: Thanks, I was accidentally calling the wrong URL.

Answer (score 0):

URL target was to webservice and not web proxy. Therefore result was XML rather than JSON.