# How to parse the xml value to json object in android?

Tags: java, android

I was used below code for parse the xml to json, but its not working

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
        // detect the view that was "clicked"
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            new LongOperation().execute("");
            break;
        }
    }

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         String url = params[0];

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);           
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Result is in String Format
        // you can use JSON api to convert into JSONObject

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

i got **error** `DefaultHttpClient file does't exist from DefaultHttpClient and HttpGet,` how to solve this error, i was passed the url is

http://webservices.amazon.in/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAsfggVPWLGL2UIWB3SA&AssociateTag=projectr0c-21&Keywords=iphone&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2CImages&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2018-06-20T05%3A31%3A25Z&Signature=JIYJVsrpWz0xj3yWS0Pxgnx%2BPtLpD9bi%2Bjek%2FhhQwN4%3D

Comment: i am not sure what you want. but if you want to convert a xml output to json, then you can try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18339178/4239410

Answer (score 0):

> There are 2 ways to create a XmlToJson object: from a String or from
>   an InputStream.

```
String xmlString; // some XML String previously created
XmlToJson xmlToJson = new XmlToJson.Builder(xmlString).build();
```

OR

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("myFile.xml");
XmlToJson xmlToJson = new XmlToJson.Builder(inputStream, null).build();
inputStream.close();
```

> Here is an example of XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library>
<owner>John Doe</owner>
<book id="007">James Bond</book>
<book id="000">Book for the dummies</book>
</library>
... converted into JSON

{ 
"library":{
"owner": "John Doe",
"book":[ 
{ 
"id":"007",
"content":"James Bond"
},
{ 
"id":"000",
"content":"Book for the dummies"
}
]
}
}
```

Custom Content names
By default, the content of a XML Tag is converted into a key called "content". This name can be changed with a custom one, using Builder.setContentName(String contentPath, String replacementName). You can change as many content names as you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library>
<book id="007">James Bond</book>
<book id="000">Book for the dummies</book>
</library>


public String convertXmlToJson(String xml) {
XmlToJson xmlToJson = new XmlToJson.Builder(xml).setContentName("/library/book", "title").build();
return xmlToJson.toString();
}
```

*json*

```
{ 
"library":{ 
"book":[ 
{ 
"id":"007",
"title":"James Bond"
},
{ 
"id":"000",
"title":"Book for the dummies"
}
]
}
}
```

Add the libary dependency to your APP build.gradle file

```
 dependencies { implementation 'com.github.smart-fun:XmlToJson:1.4.4' // add this line }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can u please tell i will add any dependency?

Comment: Add the libary dependency to your APP build.gradle file

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.smart-fun:XmlToJson:1.4.4'    // add this line
}